# Can SQL use calculate values as alias names

Tags: sql, programming-languages, partition

I am trying to find out how to use a calculated value as part of an alias name .

For example:

Select employeeName as ''name of guy' but where 'name of guy' could be getdate() + 'name o guy'
Addin qualifiers just prevents the code inside from calculating.

Is this possible in any way? I'm going to use a partition to group results by year and I need the column aliases to be based on the year thy are in

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL to have such variable names.  That is, you need to create the SQL as a string and then execute it.

Comment: I don't think so.  For any query that returns more than one row, you might have ambiguity problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's what you are looking for but it could be a good starting :

```
DECLARE @var table(rownum int, rowkey varchar(60), ALIAS varchar(80))
INSERT INTO @var SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY employeeName), employeeName, cast(getdate() AS varchar(12))+employeeName FROM Table1
DECLARE @query varchar(500)
DECLARE @rowkey varchar(60), @i int, @max int
SET @i = 1
SET @max = (SELECT count(*) FROM @var)
SET @query = ''
WHILE @i <= @max
BEGIN
    SET @rowkey = (SELECT rowkey FROM @var WHERE rownum = @i)
    SET @query = 'select employeeName as "'+(SELECT ALIAS FROM @var WHERE rowkey = @rowkey)+'" from Table1 where employeeName = '''+@rowkey+''';'
    exec(@query)
    SET @i = @i + 1
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only expecting a single value, you could use a table variable. However, if multiple rows are created it effectively becomes a temporary table. If you think that's likely, declare as a temporary table.